# Android emulator stuck in boot loop -library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found

Tags: android, loops, emulation, boot

I have tried to boot my emulator on three different platforms windows 7, ubuntu 12.04 and kubuntu 13.10(fresh install). However it always stops here with the logcat looping with the output below.

Could anyone help me figure this out. It is quite frustrating and I have lost close to a week of development.

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 3143): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<  
D/AndroidRuntime( 3143): CheckJNI is ON
E/dalvikvm( 3143): Can't create markStack
W/dalvikvm( 3143): CreateJavaVM failed: dvmGcStartup failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 3143): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
I/Netd    ( 3161): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController( 3161): Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
D/AndroidRuntime( 3162):
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into similar issue when I replaced libcrypto.so with my version. As restored /system/lib/libcrypto.so with original copy, things worked fine.

Comment: How exactly did you do this. I have tried looking around for how to restore Kernel files and all. There just does not seem to be a tutorial/ guide/ Do you mind breaking it down. ..

Answer (score 0):

This happened unexpectedly on my Android 12 emulator. It would no longer boot up, and instead just get stuck on the black screen that has the word "android" in white letters, with a gray fade animation over the letters.

[image]

The logcat output would just have repeated displays of this every 10 seconds or so:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3143): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
```

I couldn't find a way to fix it, so **I just deleted the emulator and recreated it again**, in Android Studio -> Tools -> Device Manager -> <kbd>Create Device</kbd> -> select a suitable screen size and a name -> <kbd>Next</kbd> -> press the tab "x86 Images" -> then select the Android 12 API 31 image that you have already downloaded.